# Is it possible to access android shared preference to a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am updating my current android app to flutter. Is it possible to access the sharedPreferences used in android app using the [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) plugin on flutter.

So, when the user updates the app, they are logged in directly.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but why not just try it out and see?

Comment: "I am updating my current android app to flutter" How? Are you adding Flutter inside your native Android code, or are you building a whole new Flutter project?

Comment: @AhmadF I am building a whole new Flutter Project

Comment: @Ivo I did try but I'm unable to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this package [native_shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/native_shared_preferences),
there are some method which can help you like (**containsKey()**, **getKeys()**).

this package [native_shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/native_shared_preferences) storing without adding prefix to the keys. Unlike this package [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences), where it always add a prefix to each variable stored using it

prefix: "flutter_"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to get necessary token and one int value from native apps.

First you need [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to find necessary files, [plist_parser](https://pub.dev/packages/plist_parser) for iOs because iOs stores User Defaults as .plist file, and [xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) to read .xml file with Shared Preferences in Android.

How to find iOs native values:

```
if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // Find the dir of the app.
  final appDocumentsDir = await getLibraryDirectory();
    // Create a list of contents in this dir, which includes files and dirs. 
    List contents = appDocumentsDir.listSync();
    // Find in the list the dir with user preferences
    Directory? prefsDir = contents.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element is Directory && element.path.contains('Preferences'));
    if (prefsDir != null) {
      // Get contents of the dir named 'Preferences'
      List subContents = prefsDir.listSync();
      // Find .plist file with package name of your app.
      File? prefsFile = subContents.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element is File && element.path.contains('com.your_app.plist'));
      if (prefsFile != null) {
        // Parse the file 
        final plist = PlistParser().parseBinaryFileSync(prefsFile.path);
        // With loop find necessary items
        for (final item in plist.entries) {
          if (item.key == 'access_token') {
            print('${item.value as String}');
            // your code to handle the value 
          }
          if (item.key == 'city_id') {
            print('${item.value as int}');
            // your code to handle the value 
          }
          // An example to get stored data of Swift struct 
          if (item.key == 'selectedCity') {
            // Create decoder
            const asciiDecoder = AsciiDecoder();
            // Get ASCII value, which stored like [56, 104, 92 ...]
            final asciiValues = item.value;
            // Convert it to string.
            // It returns json string
            final cityJson = asciiDecoder.convert(asciiValues);
            // Convert json to the class with its factory.
            // You may use https://app.quicktype.io to convert JSON
            // to Flutter class and create necessary factories
            final city = City.fromRawJson(cityJson);
            // your code to handle the object of this class
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How to get values from shared preferences in Android.

```
import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;
// Name it somehow you like for example 'xml' as far as it conflicts with dart.io
// You will need dart.io for Platform

if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  // Find the dir of you app by package name
  final appDocumentsDir = Directory('/data/data/com.your_app');
  // Create a list of contents in this dir, which includes files and dirs. 
  List contents = appDocumentsDir.listSync();
  // Find in the list the dir with shared preferences
  Directory? prefsDir = contents.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element is Directory && element.path.contains('shared_prefs'));
  if (prefsDir != null) {
    // Get contents of the dir named shared_prefs
    List subContents = prefsDir.listSync();
    // Find .xml file with shared preferences.
    // Check the name of this file in native code, or
    // find it in Device Explorer of Android Studio.
    File? prefsFile = subContents.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element is File && element.path.contains('your_name.xml'));
    if (prefsFile != null) {
        // Create XML document
        final document = xml.XmlDocument.parse(prefsFile.readAsStringSync());
        // Loop from root to children
        for (final items in document.children) {
          // Loop for each child
          for (final item in items.childElements) {
            // Read item as Sting
            final itemString = item.outerXml;
            // Check for your name in prefs
            if (itemString.contains('access_token')) {
              // If prefs store it as String it will look like
              // '<string name="access_token">the token value</string>'
              // Get the value in this key
              final value = item.innerXml;
              // your code to handle the value
            }
            // For int or float you need to do something different.
            // Because prefs store it like '<int name="city_id" value="3" />'
            if (itemString.contains('city_id')) {
              // 'item.attributes' will return a list like 
              // [name="city_id", value="3"]
              // and you need to get second value and parse it to int
              final cityId = int.parse(item.attributes[1].value);
              // You code to handle the value 'cityId'
            }
          }
        }
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

.firstWhereOrNull is a function from very useful lib of [getX](https://pub.dev/packages/get).
Or you may use extension below.

```
extension IterableX<T> on Iterable<T> {
  T? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(T) test) {
  T? firstItem;
  for (var item in this) {
    if (test(item)) {
      firstItem = item;
      break;
    }
  }
  return firstItem;
  }
}
```